# WhatsApp without QR code scanning everytime through Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

Is there any whatsapp or webdriver API to access WhatsApp web without scanning QR code everytime while accessing it using selenium and chrome webdriver in python?

Answer (score 3):

Your "WhatsApp" and "QR Code" don't tell anything to me, however if you're testing an application which requires an extra action to sign in I don't think you will be able to perform it using Selenium as it's **browser** automation framework.

Web applications identify users via [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) - special [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) containing client-side information. When you start a web browser via Selenium bindings - it kicks off a **clean** browser session which is not authenticated in "WhatsApp" (whatever it is)

The solutions would be in:

1. Authenticate in WhatsApp manually, store your browser profile somewhere and start Selenium by pointing it to the earlier storied profile folder
2. Authenticate in WhatsApp manually, [store your browser cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) and use [WebDriver.add_cookie()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie) function to read the stored cookies into the current clean session

Answer (score 3):

> This is What you need. This code Read QR and store it in cookies

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

jokes = ["You don't need a parachute to go skydiving. You need a parachute to go skydiving twice.",
    "This is Test Message."]

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')  # Already authenticated

time.sleep(20)

##################### Provide Recepient Name Here ###############################
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='MyJakartaNumber']").click()

for joke in jokes:
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys(joke)
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button/span').click()
 time.sleep(10)

time.sleep(30)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"pywhatkit"`. `pywhatkit` is used to send messages using whatssapp web. Run:

```
pip install pywhatkit
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: this doesn't have headless mode